# Print environment variables containing color from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, zsh, color-codes

I have a file containing a color table that sets environment variables that I use for zsh prompts. Currently have a python script that takes all the colors found between #color-begin and #color-end. However, I cannot pass python string variables into a python shell invocation and I'm unsure what the problem is.

Something like

```
pythonStr = "fg_blue"
pythonStr = "$"+fg_blue
os.system("echo + pythonStr")
```

So far I have found a few examples that pass variables into .sh files, but how does one print out a environment color variable without a .sh file? If this is not possible, why is this the case?
Here is the current python code I have and the color codes I would like to print out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

printcolor.py

```
import os
import subprocess

def prcl():

with open("appearance") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

    foo = False

    for line in content:
        line = line.strip(' \n\t')

        # Toggle boolean                                                                                                          
        if "color-" in line:
            foo = not foo

        if foo == True:
            if line is not "" and "#" not in line:
                # Use '=' as a delimiter  
                head, sep, tail = line.partition("=")
                head='"$'+head+'"'

                # prints out blank lines
                os.system("echo "+head)

                #prints literal string
                #print(head)
```

environment variables for color

```
#color-begin

fg_black=%{$'\e[0;30m'%}
fg_red=%{$'\e[0;31m'%}
fg_green=%{$'\e[0;32m'%}
fg_brown=%{$'\e[0;33m'%}
fg_blue=%{$'\e[0;34m'%}
fg_purple=%{$'\e[0;35m'%}
fg_cyan=%{$'\e[0;36m'%}
fg_lgray=%{$'\e[0;37m'%}
fg_dgray=%{$'\e[1;30m'%}
fg_lred=%{$'\e[1;31m'%}
fg_lgreen=%{$'\e[1;32m'%}
fg_yellow=%{$'\e[1;33m'%}
fg_lblue=%{$'\e[1;34m'%}
fg_pink=%{$'\e[1;35m'%}
fg_lcyan=%{$'\e[1;36m'%}
fg_white=%{$'\e[1;37m'%}
fg_blue=%{$'\e[0;34m'%}
fg_purple=%{$'\e[0;35m'%}
fg_cyan=%{$'\e[0;36m'%}
fg_lgray=%{$'\e[0;37m'%}
fg_dgray=%{$'\e[1;30m'%}
fg_lred=%{$'\e[1;31m'%}
fg_lgreen=%{$'\e[1;32m'%}
fg_yellow=%{$'\e[1;33m'%}
fg_lblue=%{$'\e[1;34m'%}
fg_pink=%{$'\e[1;35m'%}
fg_lcyan=%{$'\e[1;36m'%}
fg_white=%{$'\e[1;37m'%}

#Text Background Colors                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
bg_red=%{$'\e[0;41m'%}
bg_green=%{$'\e[0;42m'%}
bg_brown=%{$'\e[0;43m'%}
bg_blue=%{$'\e[0;44m'%}
bg_purple=%{$'\e[0;45m'%}
bg_cyan=%{$'\e[0;46m'%}
bg_gray=%{$'\e[0;47m'%}

#Attributes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
at_normal=%{$'\e[0m'%}
at_bold=%{$'\e[1m'%}
at_italics=%{$'\e[3m'%}
at_underl=%{$'\e[4m'%}
at_blink=%{$'\e[5m'%}
at_outline=%{$'\e[6m'%}
at_reverse=%{$'\e[7m'%}
at_nondisp=%{$'\e[8m'%}
at_strike=%{$'\e[9m'%}
at_boldoff=%{$'\e[22m'%}
at_italicsoff=%{$'\e[23m'%}
at_underloff=%{$'\e[24m'%}
at_blinkoff=%{$'\e[25m'%}
at_reverseoff=%{$'\e[27m'%}
at_strikeoff=%{$'\e[29m'%}

#color-end
```

Comment: just use print(), not os.system(echo ..)

Comment: I commented out "print(head)" on the last line of the python snippet.

Comment: I see. Use `os.system('/bin/bash -c "echo -e '+tail+'"')`.

Comment: `content = f.readlines()` in unnecessary.  Replace `for line in content:` with `for line in f:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several minor issues with your Python program, but the main reason why your variables are not expanded is because they are **not present in the environment** when the Python program is run.

Your `appearance` file should look like:

```
export fg_black=$'\e[0;30m'
export fg_red=$'\e[0;31m'
export fg_green=$'\e[0;32m'
```

The `%{..%}` is just unnecessary, but [`export`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-export-1) is crucial. Without `export`, after you `source appearance` in your shell, those variables are not passed onto a python process when called later from that shell with `python printcolor.py`.

Another option in `zsh` would be to use `setopt allexport` and export all environment variables to a subprocess (subshell), but that can have many undesired effects, so you're safer with individual `export`s.

After you modify your `appearance` file, you'll have to tweak color name parsing in Python, perhaps like this (the inner `if` only):

```
if line and not line.startswith("#"):
    color = line.split("=")[0].split()[1]
    subprocess.call('echo "${%s}"text' % color, shell=True)
```